# Java, comparing BigInteger values

Tags: java

```
BigInteger bigInteger = ...;


if(bigInteger.longValue() > 0) {  //original code
    //bigger than 0
}

//should I change to this?
if(bigInteger.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0)) == 1) {
    //bigger than 0
}
```

I need to compare some arbitary BigInteger values. I wonder which approach is correct. Given the above code which one should be used? The original code is on the top.. I am thinking to change it to the second approach.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The first approach is wrong if you want to test if the BigInteger has a postive value: `longValue` just returns the *low-order 64 bit* which may revert the sign... So the test could fail for a positive BigInteger.

The second approach is better (see [Bozhos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095024/java-comparing-biginteger-values/4095042#4095042) for an optimization).

Another alternative: `BigInteger#signum` returns `1` if the value is positive:

```
if (bigInteger.signum() == 1) {
 // bigger than 0
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but you mean `bigger _than_ 0` right? Just nitpicking.. :p

Comment: @Rosdi - sure, "than". Somatimas tha 'e' end tha 'a' kay chenga plecas on my kayboerd ;-)

Answer (score 32):

If you are using `BigInteger`, this assumes you need bigger numbers than `long` can handle. So don't use `longValue()`. Use `compareTo`. With your example it better be:

```
if (bigInteger.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {

}
```

Comment: True (+1), but check for ` > 0`, not `== 1` (see my answer)

Comment: @seanizer - just fixed that, and +1 to your answer for which.

Answer (score 18):

This is not a direct answer, but an important note about using compareTo().

When checking the value of compareTo(), always test for `x < 0`, `x > 0` and `x == 0`.
**Do not test for `x == 1`**

From the [Comparable.compareTo()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) javadocs:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Note:

- `A negative integer`, not `-1`.
- `A positive integer`, not `1`.

---

True, checking for `==1` and `==-1` would work for `BigInteger`. This is the `BigInteger.compareTo()` code:

```
public int compareTo(BigInteger val) {
    if (signum == val.signum) {
        switch (signum) {
        case 1:
            return compareMagnitude(val);
        case -1:
            return val.compareMagnitude(this);
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return signum > val.signum ? 1 : -1;
}
```

But it's still bad practice, and explicitly recommended against in the [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigInteger%29):

> Compares this BigInteger with the specified BigInteger. This method is provided in preference to individual methods for each of the six boolean comparison operators (<, ==, >, >=, !=, <=). **The suggested idiom for performing these comparisons is: (`x.compareTo(y) <op> 0`), where `<op>` is one of the six comparison operators.**

Comment: The spec for `BigInteger.compareTo()` does explicitly say `-1, 0, and 1` but I do agree using `x < 0`, `x == 0`, `x > 0` feels more intuitive rather than `x == -1`, `x == 0`, `x == 1`.

Comment: @Rosdi but it also says *The suggested idiom for performing these comparisons is: (`x.compareTo(y) <op> 0`), where `<op>` is one of the six comparison operators.*