# Java Integer add leading zeros?

Tags: java, integer, int

I need to add leading zeros to an array for mathematical use.
Specifically, I am making something to add two large numbers. The numbers are stored as an int array, where each element of the array is 5 digits. One example is
53498 93784 45891 45982 48933 58947
I need to add another to this, say,
23584 42389 32479 34289 39281 48237
To add them I would take the last 5 digits of both and add them 58947+48237
This gives 107184. Then I set the carry value to 1 and subtract 100,000.

This is the problem:
It sets the int to 7184, then the sum says ...882157184 instead of 8821507184, making a (very) incorrect sum.
So how do I get my Sum int array to say 88215 07184?
If this is not possible, please list another way of getting the same result, maybe a string instead of a int array? 
If at all possible, please try to find a way to have a leading 0 with an int value.

Comment: Are you looking for a way of *printing* a number with leading zeros?

Comment: Numeric values *never have leading zeros*. However, a *string representation* of a number can have leading zeros (often for human consumption). The *numeric value* is still the same, however. If you want to treat a number as a string, then do so. But know that any leading zeros *have no meaning* to the value of the number -- or `int` -- itself.

Comment: Unless this is home work, use BigInteger.  If its homework (you should add the `[homework]` tag) you shouldn't need to worry about leading zeros because all `int` values are 32-bits long regardless of their values i.e. they always have the same number of 0 or 1s.

Comment: @JTTCOTE: If an answer helped you, please don't forget to accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you considered using Java's [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class?

- [Large Numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java)
- [Java Big Integers](http://wiki.compsci.ca/index.php?title=Java_Big_Integers)
- [Java, comparing BigInteger values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095024/java-comparing-biginteger-values)
- [Converting from Integer, to BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878192/converting-from-integer-to-biginteger)

e.g.

```
BigInteger quiteBig = new BigInteger("534989378445891459824893358947");
```

Comment: +1 It sounds like he's reinventing BigInteger.  Which may be a good homework exercise, but probably not something to be done in real life.

Comment: +1 for BigIntegers; I would give you another one for the crack fox if I could

Comment: Wow, I feel kind of lame. Thanks for the quick reply guys!

Answer (score 4):

There's no leading zeros in the *value* (unless of course you're talking about octal literals). Internally, `int` is 32 bits, and that's it.

What you may need is formatting. To address the *output*, you can try `String.format("%05d", x);`, For the detais, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this:

```
class FiveDigitInteger {
  private static final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("00000");
  final int i;

  public FiveDigitInteger ( int i ) {
    this.i = i;
  }

  public int getInteger () {
    return i;
  }

  public String toString () {
    return format.format(i);
  }
}
```

and add various `math` methods such as:

```
  public FiveDigitInteger add ( int j ) {
    return new FiveDigitInteger ( i + j );
  }
```

etc.